# Laravel 5 Hosting, amsgames laravelshop

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I moved from local development where everything worked just fine to shared hosting. Now i keep getting this error when it has anything to do with logging in or registering a user. Please help! I have a deadline to meet!

[image]

Comment: What is the error, Nick?

Comment: Please post actual error messages instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure your config is configurated properly, so the code knows which directory to find where you defined the trait. Other than that, all we can do here is guess if you cannot isolate the error for us.

Comment: Did you make sure to run composer update on the server?